# What is the use case of annotated tuple type in Erlang?

Tags: erlang

I found the below type specification in Erlang module. I am trying to understand how is it used? Is it similar to record?

```
-type timestamp() :: {MegaSecs :: non_neg_integer(),
                      Secs :: non_neg_integer(),
                      MicroSecs :: non_neg_integer()}.
```

Comment: I think you have to be more specific with your question. "Similar to record" in what sense?
This is a type specification for a tuple with 3 elements.
This is not an annotated tuple (which would have an atom as its first element).
Records are actually tuples, that's right… but I bet you're asking something deeper than that.

Comment: I was not able to understand why do we need to specify the name of the element and type in the tuple.

Comment: @vrnithinkumar, Short answer: ignore what you saw and don't worry about it.  Longer answer: Erlang variables don't have types which makes debugging harder.  In other languages, which have types, the compiler can identify errors in your code.  Erlang has some facilities for marking the types of variables, which something called Dialyzer can examine and see if your code is consistent with the type markings in your code.  Dialyzer is an effort to help debug your code.  Even without Dialyzer, type markings in your code serve to document what your code is supposed to do.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. 
I got confused with why do why do we need to specify the name of the element in the tuple? 
In type spec page the type syntax for Tuple is  `Tuple :: tuple() | {} | {TList}` without element names.

Comment: The tuple type is pretty general.  For instance, a tuple can contain negative integers, atoms, and 20 elements.  For the type in your example, the programmer wanted to create a type that was more specific than just a tuple, so they declared a type that is a tuple with three elements where each element is a non-negative integer.

Comment: You could omit the variable names MegaSecs, Secs, and MicroSecs in the type definition, but they serve to document what goes where in the tuple, and automated documentation tools also make use of the variable names.

Comment: Thanks!
So basically it is similar to this `{non_neg_integer(), non_neg_integer(), non_neg_integer()}`, a tuple with three elements of type `non_neg_integer()`

Answer (score 3):

> I found the below type specification in Erlang module. I am trying to
> understand how is it used? Is it similar to record?
>
> ```
> -type timestamp() :: {MegaSecs :: non_neg_integer(),
>                       Secs :: non_neg_integer(),
>                       MicroSecs :: non_neg_integer()}.
> ```

No, it is a user defined type.

> ...types can be used to specify types of record fields and also the
> argument and return types of functions.
>
> Type information can be used for the following:
>
> To document function interfaces
> To provide more information for bug
> detection tools, such as Dialyzer
> To be exploited by documentation
> tools, such as EDoc, for generating program documentation of various
> forms

For more information about types, see:

http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/typespec.html

and:

https://learnyousomeerlang.com/dialyzer

Here is an example:

```
-module(a).
-compile(export_all).

-type timestamp() :: {MegaSecs :: non_neg_integer(),
                      Secs :: non_neg_integer(),
                      MicroSecs :: non_neg_integer()}.

-record(bill, {name :: string(),
               amount :: non_neg_integer(),
               date :: timestamp() 
              }
        ).
-type bill() :: #bill{}.

-spec payment_due(bill()) -> timestamp().
payment_due(Bill) ->
    {Mega, Sec, Micro} = Bill#bill.date,
    {Mega+1, Sec, Micro}.
```

In the shell:

```
1> c(a).                                                        
a.erl:2: Warning: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported
{ok,a}

2> rr(a).                                                       
[bill]

3> Bill = #bill{name="John", amount=30, date={3, 2, 1}}.
#bill{name = "John",amount = 30,date = {3,2,1}}

4> a:payment_due(Bill).                                         
{4,2,1}
```

Dialyzer:

```
~/erlang_programs$ dialyzer --build_plt --apps erts kernel stdlib crypto mnesia sasl commotest eunit
  Compiling some key modules to native code... done in 0m35.60s
  Creating PLT /Users/7stud/.dialyzer_plt ...
...
...
done (passed successfully)

~/erlang_programs$ dialyzer a.erl
  Checking whether the PLT /Users/7stud/.dialyzer_plt is up-to-date... yes
  Proceeding with analysis... done in 0m0.15s
done (passed successfully)
```